# Keep Getting : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, unexpected-token

The javascript debugger says on line 3 the curly bracket is an unexpected token.
Can anyone please help me out with this?

```
setTimeout(rollDice, (multiplier * bconfig.wait) + Math.round(Math.random() 
* 1000));
};

toggleHiLo = function() {
  if (hilo === 'hi') {
    hilo = 'hi';
  } else {
    hilo = 'hi';
  }
};
var num = parseFloat($('#balance').html());
bconfig.startbal = num;
bconfig.want = num ;
bconfig.autoexit = num - 10000;
rollDice();
```

Comment: well they are unexpected, you can remove them completely

Comment: Can I ask you why did you put it ? where is the opening of it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `};` from the 3rd line, because you don't need it at all.

Code:

```
setTimeout(rollDice, (multiplier * bconfig.wait) + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));

toggleHiLo = function() {
  if (hilo === 'hi') {
    hilo = 'hi';
  } else {
    hilo = 'hi';
  }
};
var num = parseFloat($('#balance').html());
bconfig.startbal = num;
bconfig.want = num ;
bconfig.autoexit = num - 10000;
rollDice();
```

Comment: But now javascript says → Uncaught ReferenceError: rollDice is not defined

Comment: `rollDice` - it's a function, according to your code. You need to implement/define it at the top.
The same with `multiplier`, but `bconfig` - it's an object.

Comment: @Retro— *rollDice* is seen as an identifier, but there is no default *rollDice* property of the global object and you've not created any variable called *rollDice* (in the OP code), hence the error: *rollDice is not defined*.